# Canvas Selection Tool? wxpython

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

Is there a way to make a canvas selection tool in wxpython?

LEFT BUTTON PRESSED:
When the left button is pressed start drawing rectangle and update it until the user releases the left button.

LEFT BUTTON RELEASED:
Finish drawing rectangle

It is something similar that you would see in a paint program.

[image]

If possible please provide an example.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to do it with [wx.Overlay](http://wxpython-users.1045709.n5.nabble.com/wx-Overlay-td2354977.html)

Answer (score 1):

You have an example of a drawing canvas in the source code downloads from [wxPython in Action](http://www.manning.com/rappin/).
This is a canvas for freehand sketching. You can start from there to expand its functionality.

The simpler example is example1.py from Chapter-06 folder. There are several other examples in the same chapter with increasing functionality.

For an example of a drawing tool selector and how to move and modify the objects selected and set in a frame I would recommend to look at the code of the [wxglade GUI designer](http://wxglade.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Where can I find the example of the drawing canvas online?

Comment: in the link I provided !. You have to download the source code for the examples of the book in that page

Comment: I downloaded it, but their is nothing titled drawing canvas

Comment: The simpler example is example1.py from Chapter-06 folder. There are several other examples in the same chapter with increasing functionality.

Comment: Ah yes however there is no rectangle canvas tool within this example

Comment: For an example of a drawing tool selector and how to move and modify the objects selected and set in a frame I would recommend to look at the code of the wxglade GUI designer.

Comment: hmm, i cant seem to find exactly where the code is.. can you enlighten me?

Answer (score 1):

The Whyteboard application has a selection tool that you could use for inspiration. You can get it here: http://whyteboard.org/ It's written in wxPython. By the way, the wxPython mailing list is a great place to ask questions too.